# Reactjs - How to access nested keys in a json with dynamic values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization

I have made a React context to access i18n translations, as well as a function called "t" to access the desired value. It works well for simple keys, but not for nested keys. Here is my context:

```js
export function I18nProvider({ children }) {
  const [locale, setLocale] = useState<Locales>("en");
  const translations = { ch, fr, sw, en };
  return (
    <I18nContext.Provider value={{ translations, locale, setLocale }}>
      {children}
    </I18nContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function t(key: string) {
  const { translations, locale } = useContext(I18nContext);
  return useMemo(() => translations[locale][key], [locale, translations, id]);
}
```

And here is t() in action:

```js
<div>{t("form.username")}</div>;
```

Obviously, it can't work because `t()` returns `translations["en"]["form.username"]` which is incorrect. I tried to allow subfields in `t()` parameters: `t("form", "username")` and returned `translations[locale][key][sub]`. It worked, but then failed when I used a single key.

How to make t() generic? I thought about reformatting my t parameter, but if such an action runs for each translation, I'm afraid it will be bad for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a helper function which accept as parameters the object and the path to return the deep value :

and use it like :

```
export function t(key: string) {
  const { translations, locale } = useContext(I18nContext);
  return useMemo(() => getDeepNestedFieldValue(locale+'.'+key,translations), [locale, translations, id]);
}
```

**Example in pure JS** :

```js
const getDeepNestedFieldValue = (path, obj) => {
  return path.split('.').reduce((p, c) => (p && p[c]) || null, obj);
}
let user = {
  name: {
    first: 'John',
    last: 'Doe'
  },
  address: {
    city: {
      name: 'Cairo',
    }
  }
}


console.log(getDeepNestedFieldValue('name.first', user))
console.log(getDeepNestedFieldValue('address.city.name', user))
```

Comment: It works thanks! However, why don't you just write: split('.').reduce((p, c) => p[c], obj) ?

Comment: returning `null` if the condition  `(p && p[c])` is not verified instead of returning undefined